# Connected Web Parts on Document Set Homepage Causing Error

Tags: 2013, document-set, query-string, connected-web-parts

On my document set homepage I have added two list view web parts.

These two web parts are connected so the second is filtered based on the first.

[image]

Environment 1 is selected by default on page load. The problem I have is when I select Environment 2 or Environment 3, I see an error message:

[image]

The interesting messages in the ULS logs:

> Name=Request (POST:[site]/Applications/Forms/Application/docsethomepage.aspx?View=%7B152431A0%2D9A5D%2D499F%2D8789%2D7A67608F64C3%7D&SelectedID=3&ID=4)

And...

> Application error when access [site]/Applications/Forms/Application/docsethomepage.aspx, Error=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.DocSetWelcomePageControl.BuildV15BreadcrumbScript()
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.DocSetWelcomePageControl.RenderBreadcrumb()
>    at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.DocSetWelcomePageControl.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AjaxDelta.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter output)
>    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AjaxDelta.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>    at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SharePointForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>    at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.RenderToBase(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>    at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>    at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

And...

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.     at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.DocSetWelcomePageControl.BuildV15BreadcrumbScript()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.DocSetWelcomePageControl.RenderBreadcrumb()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.DocSetWelcomePageControl.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AjaxDelta.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.AjaxDelta.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SharePointForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ICollection children)      at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.RenderToBase(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.DeltaPage.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   writer)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter)      at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

My guess is when I select Environment 2 the javascript is trying to change the URL to the one specified in the first error message above, but then this is causing a problem showing the document set because it's removing the query string parameters that are normally present on a document set homepage.

For info, the URL to the document set homepage is:

```
[site]/Applications/Forms/Application/docsethomepage.aspx?ID=4&FolderCTID=0x0120D52000097B2AAED9957E4CAD8855E43B2B0C6F00341030E5B70A6A4D9C605B8C48983359&List=3d911efd-eed7-4019-86c3-ed109b796891&RootFolder=[site]%2FApplications%2FTest%20app%202&RecSrc=[site]%2FApplications%2FTest%20app%202
```

When I hover over the arrows in the Select column, this is the URL I see:

```
javascript:SelectField('{152431A0-9A5D-499F-8789-7A67608F64C3}','3');return false;
```

If this is indeed a URL and query string problem, is there a way I can tap into this javascript function and prevent it from stripping all the query string parameters?

**UPDATE**

I should have added that the URL on the error page is this:

```
[site]/Applications/Forms/Application/docsethomepage.aspx?View=%7B152431A0-9A5D-499F-8789-7A67608F64C3%7D&SelectedID=3&ID=4
```

So it does look like the `SelectField` function is stripping the query string parameters that are necessary for the document set homepage to display correctly.

But then the next question is, if I was to change the URL manually, what can I put in for this to work? I have already tried:

```
[site]/Applications/Forms/Application/docsethomepage.aspx?ID=4&FolderCTID=0x0120D52000097B2AAED9957E4CAD8855E43B2B0C6F00341030E5B70A6A4D9C605B8C48983359&List=3d911efd-eed7-4019-86c3-ed109b796891&RootFolder=[site]%2FApplications%2FTest%20app%202&RecSrc=[site]%2FApplications%2FTest%20app%202&View=%7B152431A0-9A5D-499F-8789-7A67608F64C3%7D&SelectedID=3&ID=4
```

But strangely, this just navigates to the root of the Applications document library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to manually navigate to the doc set, here's the correct URL:

```
[site]/Applications/Forms/Application/docsethomepage.aspx?ID=4&FolderCTID=0x0120D52000097B2AAED9957E4CAD8855E43B2B0C6F00341030E5B70A6A4D9C605B8C48983359&List=3d911efd-eed7-4019-86c3-ed109b796891&RootFolder=[site]%2FApplications%2FTest%20app%202&RecSrc=[site]%2FApplications%2FTest%20app%202&View=%7B152431A0-9A5D-499F-8789-7A67608F64C3%7D&SelectedID=3
```

Note that I removed the final `ID=4`: it's already present as the first parameter. That's the one that defines the doc set to display. If it's duplicated, the doc set selection fails, and the page falls back to the root of the doc lib.
Also that once you've navigated with the above-mentioned URL, you can change the provider selection, strangely with no error anymore!

**EDIT**
OK, I finally managed to make it work.

1. First, edit your Doc Set page, and add a Script Editor Web part
2. Edit the Snippet of the Script WP and add this code:

   ```
   <script type='text/javascript'>

   function MyCustomSelectField(view, selectID) {
   var strDocUrl = ajaxNavigate.get_href();
   var strHash = ajaxNavigate.get_hash();
   var fViewReplaced = false;
   var pattern = /\#.*/i;

   strDocUrl = strDocUrl.replace(pattern, "");
   var viewGuid = GetUrlKeyValue("View", true);
   var pageView = GetUrlKeyValue("PageView", true);
   var idForm = GetUrlKeyValue("ID", true);
   var contentTypeIdForm = GetUrlKeyValue("ContentTypeId", true);

   if (view.toUpperCase() != viewGuid.toUpperCase()) {
       var encodedView = escapeProperly(view);

       if (encodedView.toUpperCase() != viewGuid.toUpperCase()) {
           pattern = /\?[^?]*/i;
           var idxQuery = strDocUrl.indexOf("?");

           if (idxQuery != -1) {
               var idxView = strDocUrl.indexOf("View=", idxQuery);
               if(idxView != -1)
                   strDocUrl = strDocUrl.replace(/\?.*View=[^&]*/, "View=" + encodedView);
               else
                   strDocUrl = strDocUrl + "&View=" + encodedView;
           }
           else
               strDocUrl = strDocUrl + "?View=" + encodedView;
           fViewReplaced = true;
       }
   }
   if (!fViewReplaced && GetUrlKeyValue("SelectedID") != "") {
       var selectIDOld = /&SelectedID=[^&]*/gi;

       strDocUrl = strDocUrl.replace(selectIDOld, "");
       selectIDOld = /\?SelectedID=[^&]*&?/;
       strDocUrl = strDocUrl.replace(selectIDOld, "?");
   }
   strDocUrl = strDocUrl + "&SelectedID=";
   strDocUrl = strDocUrl + selectID;
   if (fViewReplaced && pageView != "") {
       strDocUrl = strDocUrl + "&PageView=" + pageView;
   }
   if (idForm != "") {
       strDocUrl = strDocUrl + "&ID=" + idForm;
   }
   if (contentTypeIdForm != "") {
       strDocUrl = strDocUrl + "&ContentTypeId=" + contentTypeIdForm;
   }
   if (strHash != "") {
       strDocUrl = strDocUrl + strHash;
   }
   _SubmitFormPost(strDocUrl);
   return false;
   }

   var oldCoreInvoke = CoreInvoke;
   CoreInvoke = function (fn) {
   if (fn == '_SelectField')
       MyCustomSelectField(arguments[1], arguments[2]);
   else
       oldCoreInvoke.apply(this, arguments);
   }

   </script>
   ```
3. Close the page, test :)

What it does (OK, its not that clean, but when it comes to bugs in default JavaScript files, you don't really have choice :(...):

1. It overrides the default `SelectField` function. To do this, we also override `CoreInvoke` (at the end of the code above). Indeed, `CoreInvoke` dynamically calls default `SelectField`. So we needed to override it as well.
2. The new `SelectField` (`MyCustomSelectField`) changes:

   ```
   if (idxQuery != -1)
       strDocUrl = strDocUrl.replace(pattern, "?View=" + encodedView);
   else
       strDocUrl = strDocUrl + "?View=" + encodedView;
   ```

   (where the problem was lying, since `strDocUrl.replace(pattern...` removed all the current query string) to:

   ```
    if (idxQuery != -1) {
       var idxView = strDocUrl.indexOf("View=", idxQuery);
       if(idxView != -1)
           strDocUrl = strDocUrl.replace(/\?.*View=[^&]*/, "View=" + encodedView);
       else
           strDocUrl = strDocUrl + "&View=" + encodedView;
   }
   else
       strDocUrl = strDocUrl + "?View=" + encodedView;
   ```

**EDIT 2**
A new version of the JavaScript code, that should avoid all duplicates in the query string:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
// Add / Update a key-value pair in the URL query parameters
function updateUrlParameter(uri, key, value) {
    // remove the hash part before operating on the uri
    var i = uri.indexOf('#');
    var hash = i === -1 ? '' : uri.substr(i);
    uri = i === -1 ? uri : uri.substr(0, i);

    var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
    var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
    if (uri.match(re)) {
        uri = uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
    } else {
        uri = uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
    }
    return uri + hash;  // finally append the hash as well
}


function MyCustomSelectField(view, selectID) {
    var strDocUrl = ajaxNavigate.get_href();

    strDocUrl = updateUrlParameter(strDocUrl, "View", view);
    strDocUrl = updateUrlParameter(strDocUrl, "SelectedID", selectID);

    _SubmitFormPost(strDocUrl);
    return false;
}


var oldCoreInvoke = CoreInvoke;
    CoreInvoke = function (fn) {
        if (fn == '_SelectField')
            MyCustomSelectField(arguments[1], arguments[2]);
        else
            oldCoreInvoke.apply(this, arguments);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Progress! (I should have spotted that duplicated parameter). So then, to make the whole thing work, the original part of my question: how can I get around the `SelectField` function stripping query string parameters?

Comment: Awesome. I'll give this a shot in a couple of hours. It looks like you've taken the default `SelectField` function and are doing something with it. Can you give some explanation please?

Comment: Edited my answer to add a short explanation of the code.

Comment: You're a legend :) Works as expected. However, the URL seems to have duplicates of the ID parameter. The end of the URL looks like this when I start switching between Environment 1, 2 and 3: `View=%7B152431A0-9A5D-499F-8789-7A67608F64C3%7D&ID=4&ID=4&ID=4&ID=4&InitialTabId=Ribbon%2ERead&VisibilityContext=WSSTabPersistence&ID=4&ID=4&SelectedID=4&ID=4`. Regardless of this, your solution works.

Comment: And can we say also that this issue was perhaps as a result of an oversight on Microsoft's part in not testing connected web parts on document set homepages?

Comment: To your first comment: yes, I noticed that behavior, but it was even there before the new version of `SelectField`. I'll look to see if this can be improved.

Comment: To your second comment: yes, I think we can say that :) However, they could also have suspected (without testing) that `strDocUrl = strDocUrl.replace(pattern, "?View=" + encodedView);` may lead to some problems when the page as query params in addition to those used for the connection...

Comment: We love you Microsoft. Really, we do! Evariste, can't award bounty for another 18 hours, but it's yours. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Edited to add a new version of the code that should avoid duplicates. Completely rewrote the way we add/edit query string params, with the help of https://gist.github.com/niyazpk/f8ac616f181f6042d1e0.

Comment: Me again... Sorry, there was a bug in both versions of code I posted. This bug prevented the page to be edited. So the code is now OK regarding this (note the new version: `oldCoreInvoke.apply(this, arguments);` at the end). If you need to remove the previous Script Editor WP and you cannot switch to `Edit` mode, simple add `&contents=1` at the end of the URL to switch to maintenance mode and remove the (erroneous) Script Editor WP.

Comment: Hadn't actually tried editing the page, thanks for the update :)

Comment: Ah, with your updated code when I click the cog icon, nothing happens. The original code works fine in this regard.

Comment: Hum, not being able to click the cog icon was typically what I wanted to fix! I tested again, and the very last version is OK on my side regarding this.

Comment: My bad, I added your extra line in the wrong place. Working beautifully.